# How I can Delete Record from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete this record ? [image]

**Because I don't know what exactly it is, I want to know what it is... I expect that it is a special key for every data I upload it creates it automatically How do I delete and what is this key?**

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("poll_post").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        String postid = reference.push().getKey();

        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
        hashMap.put("time_post", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        hashMap.put("stopcomment", checked);

        hashMap.put("tv_question", addcomment.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("tvoption1", Answer1.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("tvoption2", Answer2.getText().toString());
        hashMap.put("vote1","0");
        hashMap.put("vote2", "0");

        hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        reference.push().setValue(hashMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                //Problem with saving the data
                if (databaseError != null) {


                    Toast.makeText(Write_poll.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    myLoadingButton.showErrorButton();

                } else {


                    myLoadingButton.showDoneButton();
              finish();
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) and read about the function called `push` , they clearly said that

> push  : Add to a list of data in the database. Every time you push a new node onto a list, your database generates a unique key, like messages/users//

so that's means that every time you are pushing to the database , a new record with a unique **ID** will be generated every you push and you will not be able to override a record using the function `push` as every time it's called , it will generate a unique ID that you don' want in your case.

to avoid that , instead of

```
reference.push().setValue(hashMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener(){ . . . }
```

write :

```
reference.setValue(hashMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener(){ . . . }
```

Comment: Can you please explain how can the OP use this solution to delete that record from the Realtime Database?

Comment: @AlexMamo , his problem wasn't deleting a record from the real-time database , I read what his problem, he said ".. I expect that it is a special key for every data I upload it creates it automatically How do I delete and what is this key?" , so actually his problem was that every time he upload something to the database to update ,  a new record was created not updated , so the problem was the function push , I know it's a misleading title , but his problem wasn't actually deleting a node , his problem was to avoid the creation of a new node when uploading

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a record from the Realtime Database, you have to create a reference that points to that node. In your particular case it would be:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
db.child("poll_post").child("-NBcO...y8cX").removeValue();
```

If you don't know the key, then you have to create a query to find that post based on something that uniquely identifies it, for example, the `time_post`. So here is the code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query queryByTime = db.child("poll_post").orderByChild("time_post").equalTo(1662830174410);
queryByTime.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                ds.getRef().removeValue();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

You can also attach a listener to the `removeValue()` operation to see if something goes wrong.